# Merging objects within an array and keeping the highest value for identical properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have this array and I would like to merge the objects within it.

```
[null, null, {"1":1},{"2":1},{"3":1},{"2":2},{"5":1}]
```

I thought about using something like this:

```js
var o1 = { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 };
var o2 = { b: 2, c: 2 };
var o3 = { c: 3 };

var obj = Object.assign({}, o1, o2, o3);
console.log(obj); // { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

However, the properties are overwritten by other objects that have the same properties **later in the parameters order**

What I want is to keep the **highest value** available for the same property.

In my example, I have `{"2":1}` and `{"2":2}`, I would like to keep the `{"2":2}` because `2` is the highest value available for the `"2"` property.

I want to end up with this object: `{"1":1,"2":2,"3":1,"5":1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array#reduce` to convert the array to an object, and iterate the keys of each object in the array using `Array#forEach`.

**Note: I've updated your test case to have higher values before lower values, to better demonstrate the solution.**

```js
const arr = [null, null, {"1":0},{"2":3},{"5": 25},{"3":1},{"2":2},{"5":1},{"1":-5}];

const result = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  if(!typeof(o) === 'object' || o === null) {
    return r;
  }
  
  Object.keys(o) // iterate the keys
    .forEach((key) => r[key] = r[key] !== undefined ? Math.max(r[key], o[key]) : o[key]); // get the greatest value
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) from [Lodash](https://lodash.com) library.

```
var input = [null, null, {"1":1},{"2":1},{"3":1},{"2":2},{"5":1}];
var output = _.mergeWith({}, ...input, (obj, src) => obj > src ? obj : src);
```

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla javascript:

```js
function getData(obj) {
    var d = {};
    for (var index in obj) {
        var item = obj[index];
        for (var k in item) {
            if (!d[k]) d[k] = item[k];
            else d[k] = Math.max(d[k], item[k]);
        }
    }
    console.log(d);
    return d;
}
getData([null, null, { "1": 1 }, { "2": 1 }, { "3": 1 }, { "2": 2 }, { "5": 1 }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Libraries increase vendor size, So don't prefer it for such small purpose.

```js
let input = [null, null, {"1":1},{"2":1},{"3":1},{"2":2},{"5":1}];
let output = {};

for(i in input) {
   let item = input[i];
   for(j in item)
     output[j] = item[j];
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Are you sure it's always keeping the highest value for every property?